# SQL query to find parent & child with diffeent member

Tags: sql

We have few tables like this

```
project_table 
{
    pid          // project id, which is unique
    project_name // name
    parent_proj   //some project can have parent project, if parent_proj is NULL, this project dont get parent
    project_members //this same as pid or null
}

project_member_table
{
   pid       // project id
   member_id // member id see member tbale
}

member_table
{
   member_id   //unique member id
   member_name 
   member_privilege  //application specific
}
```

create first project `proj1` with project member `member1` and `member2`
then create second project `proj2` and set `proj1` as it parent which include project member `member1`, `member2` and `member3`
Now project_table table looks like

```
pid    project_name   parent_prj  project_member  
1001    proj1          NULL          1001
1002    proj2          1001          1002
```

Now project_member_table and member_table looks like,
member_table

```
member_id , member_name, member_privilege
9001        member1         READ/WRITE
9002        member2         READ
9003        member3         WRITE
```

project_member_table

```
pid    member_id
1001   9001
1001   9002
1002   9001
1002   9002
1002   9003
```

Now, we want to create a query and find following logic:
find all the project's project_member and compared with its parent, if child project and parent project with different project member, then output these member. in our case,
proj2's parent project is `proj1`, `proj2` get project member `{member1, member2, member3}`
proj1 get project member `{member1, member2}` which are different.
so query should output `proj2, member3`

can anyone give some idea how to create this SQL thanks

Comment: Sql Server and Oracle are very different products - tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can create a collection data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list AS TABLE OF INTEGER;
```

Then aggregate the members into collections for each project and use a hierarchical query to get the parent-child relationship and the `MULTISET EXCEPT` set operator to compare the child to the parent:

```sql
SELECT pid,
       (
         SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_VALUE, ', ')
                  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE)
         FROM   TABLE(members MULTISET EXCEPT parent_members)
       ) AS added_members
FROM   (
  SELECT p.pid,
         COALESCE(members, INT_LIST()) AS members,
         COALESCE(PRIOR members, INT_LIST()) AS parent_members
  FROM   project_table p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (
           SELECT pid,
                  CAST(COLLECT(member_id ORDER BY member_id) AS int_list) AS members
           FROM   member_table
           GROUP BY pid
         ) m
         ON (p.pid = m.pid)
  WHERE  LEVEL = 2
  AND    (  PRIOR members IS NULL AND members IS NOT NULL
         OR PRIOR members IS NOT NULL AND members IS NULL
         OR PRIOR members <> members )
  CONNECT BY PRIOR p.pid = p.parent_prj
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE project_table (pid, project_name, parent_prj, project_member) AS
SELECT 1001, 'proj1', NULL, 1001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 'proj2', 1001, 1002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1003, 'proj3', NULL, 1003 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1004, 'proj4', 1003, 1004 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE member_table (pid, member_id) AS
SELECT 1001, 9001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 9002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 9001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 9002 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 9003 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1004, 9001 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1004, 9002 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PID | ADDED_MEMBERS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1002 | 9003 |
> | 1004 | 9001, 9002 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=46abdb616bb0e8de78292f197f52dbea)*